# Generating Random agent arrival in Anylogic simulation software

Tags: optimization, simulation, anylogic

I have a **schedule1** button in my ATM model that schedules the arrival of customer in source, as shown in figure. The properties of `schedule1` are shown. For source I have defined arrival by arrival schedule and the reference is schedule 1.

Currently in **schedule1** i have set type as integer and the value is 1000. i want this value to be between 1000 and 2000 at random. How can i do it.

Also based on current logic, when i run simulation i see 1000 people standing always in Queue despite being served by Atm. Queue length should decrease but it is not the case.

And i tried to change type of schedule as rate, but i'm getting error as `Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ScheduleWithUnits<RateUnits> to Schedule<Integer>. Location: Model-testt/Main/source - Source`

Kindly looking for help. Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: Hey, SOF works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You actually ask *several* questions at once. Please split these into several, separate questions. This helps you and others in the future with similar problems. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Just picking one of the several questions you raised:

> Currently in schedule1 i have set type as integer and the value is 1000. i want this value to be between 1000 and 2000 at random. How can i do it.

This is not possible easily with your setup. Either, you create schedules dynamically using the [Schedule API](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/data/schedule-api.html), or you change the entire setup.

You could setup dynamic events that trigger between the required times at the required rate. But that is also not trivial.

The easiest approach to this specific problem is probably to create a Rate-based schedule that creates agents with a rate of 1500 per hr (which is Poisson distributed). But you only use the agents during the required hrs, else you discard them into a sink (using a SelectOutput block)...

Comment: I would have edited the question, but I am not allowed to. So I will add this comment to answer another question that has been asked above. `And i tried to change type of schedule as rate, but i'm getting error as Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ScheduleWithUnits<RateUnits> to Schedule<Integer>. Location: Model-testt/Main/source - Source"` - You have a source block. Set `Arrivals defined by` to `Rate schedule`. That will solve this issue.